# Dynamically generate comma with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I'm trying to dynamically generate a comma between an iterated list of items. It's a little tricky because if there is an item in `{floor.fields.spacesText}` I want to display the comma, but if not, I want to display nothing. Is there an elegant way to do this using JavaScript?

```
const spacesText = (
  <React.Fragment>
    {typy(floor, 'fields.spacesLinks').safeArray.map(link => {
      const linkPath = link.fields.url || link.fields.slug
      const comma = ', '
      return <React.Fragment><Link to={`${linkPath}`}>{link.fields.title}</Link>{comma}</React.Fragment>
    })}
    {floor.fields.spacesText}
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Just assign to `comma` based on your condition?

Comment: Sorry, new at this, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you know how to use an `if` statement?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to identify the condition or type the proper syntax. What I want to do is:
if (floor.fields.spaceText) is empty, then '', else ', ' but I don't know how to incorporate that logic into the return statement.

Comment: Don't put it inside the return statement. Use `let comma = ', '; if (floor.fields.spaceText == '') comma = '';`

Comment: This is the same, right? `const comma = (floor.fields.spaceText == '') ? ', ' : ' '` When I do this, it won't return the comma?

Comment: Yes, you can use the conditional operator as well, I would even consider it cleaner. But notice you now inverted the condition, I thought you wanted no comma if spaceText is empty?

Comment: Thanks, Bergi! I was typing the field name incorrectly which is why it was returning no comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good use-case for a ternary statement:

```
const comma = floor.fields.spaceText ? ', ' : '';
```